# Project has "imaginary" errors in build path I can't fix

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

My eclipse project come from my company versioning system (svn), and I have the same codebase as my colleagues. However, in a number of projects I have an exclamation mark like this [image].

In the "Problems View" I have tons of `Project 'A' is missing required Java project: 'B'`. Project A and B are both in eclipse, with no other errors than this.

Every project builds correctly. Sometimes, a generated class isn't properly located by eclipse so I get red lines everywhere in the file, but the maven build still yields 'SUCCESS'.

I've tried refreshing, cleaning, force updating, with no success. I don't know where to look, because everything works fine except the build path that I have no control over (it's all done automatically). `pom.xml` files are up to date. How do I fix this?

Comment: By "_force updating_" do you mean `mvn -U|--update-snapshots ...` or _Update project_ ([Alt]+[F5]) inside Eclipse?

Comment: @GeroldBroser [Alt]+[F5] then selecting "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"

Comment: Have you seen [Project 'X' is missing required Java project: 'Y'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050997/1744774) already?